# How many inodes do I need to access to read a file?

Tags: filesystems, inode

Imagine I want to access the blocks of file `/hello/file`.
How many inodes should I walt through?

I guess two, since I should not go through the root inode, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect three `/`, `hello` and `file`.  Changing permissions of any one of these can limit access to `file`.

Comment: Shouldn't the root directory entries be already in our disk in a special block, from which we can already read where the /hello is, without looking at the / inode?

Comment: @graphtheory92 The root directory is just another inode.  However it is a very important inode.  When you mount a disk partition, its root partions inode is referenced in place of the inode of the mount point on the disk you are mounting to.

Comment: @graphtheory92: It depends on what you mean by "walting" (walking?) through an inode.  Yes, the root inode (and probably at least part of the root directory) will be cached in system memory, so reading from the disk should not be necessary.  But, if you reference a filename (pathname) beginning with `/`, then the kernel must access that cached root inode to verify that you have permission to access (traverse) it, and to find the directory blocks (some of which are probably already in memory, and some of which may still need to be read from the disk).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: @graphtheory92: (Cont’d) …  By contrast, if you are *in* the `/hello` directory, and you try to open the `file` file, you will access two inodes: `/hello` (although you may not know its name; you access it *as **the current directory***) and `file`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there are no symbolic links or mount points involved Bill gives a good answer. If there are symbolic links involved, the number would be much higher. Also if there are mounts involved you would need two inodes per mount point instead of one.

Comment: why two inodes?

Comment: one on each file system. the sequence would be read a directory to get an inode, lookup the inode, note that the inode is a mountpoint, lookup the root inode on the mounted filesystem.